# java scriptengine extract info about function

Tags: javascript, java, scriptengine

i have this as input for scriptengine. Lets name it as module(like LLVM does)

```
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName ("JavaScript");
    String script = "function foo(p1, p2)"+
                              "{"+
                              "    return p1*p2 + goo(p1,p2);"+
                              "}";

              engine.eval (script);
engine.eval (script);
```

How can i receive all functions defined in(parsed by) this engine?
For now i can only get from engine list of all globals, like global variables or functions in global scope (like foo). How to create array with all functions and their interfaces defined in module?

As you can see function `goo` is not defined in this module. Its supposed to be defined in another machine. Obv, this module will fail during execution. How to catch call of this function? I mean in LLVM you can receive all dependencies of module before execution and resolve them, or you can replace calls of such functions with your own implementation that resolves it during execution. So, how to get all dependencies of module and replace those calls with my own implementation?

Comment: This is an interesting question, however it is rather hard to understand. You should clarify your post a bit.